# How to display average in an SSRS table?

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2008 and one of my rows is supposed to return the average of a certain field.  But currently it just displays all of the rows instead of one row with the average.  How do I implement this?

Currently the stored proc for this RDL file returns all of the records.  So I tried using the "`Avg(<field value>)`" function in SSRS for the SSRS expression.  And then I grouped this row on the `<field value>`.  I removed filtering so it should average all rows now.

I'm guessing the cause is the grouping.  Any ideas though?

Comment: I know this is old, but due it's without accepted answer: did you try group your rows?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a totals row. Right-click on the group and then `Add Totals` Then you should be able to put your `Avg(<field value>)` in that cell.